Exodus 17:16 – Throne of G-d or secret hand?
This passage has been notoriously difficult for translators, with nearly every translation rendering it differently and making notes of uncertainty. Different attempts at rendering the Hebrew words vary broadly.
After Moses set up an altar and calls it "HaShem is My Banner", what does the following verse actually say?
JPS

And he said: ‘The hand upon the throne of Y-h: HaShem will have
war with Amalek from generation to generation.’

Instead of kisse-yah, the LXX translators read kesuyah, from the root k-s-h, ‘to hide’. The ‘hidden hand’ is specific to the Septuagint.
LXX

For he said, "with a secret hand HaShem wages war against Amalek from generation to
generation.

Which translation is correct?

The first. The second has no relation to the Hebrew.

Why did the LXX translators render kesuyah as "covered hand" instead of "throne of Y-h"?

https://www.sefaria.org/David_Zvi_Hoffmann_on_Exodus.17.16.1?lang=bi&with=all

Even if you interpret כס to mean "secret thing" rather than "throne", the LXX translation is incorrect. A precise translation (if using the "secret thing" meaning) is, "For a hand upon the secret thing of God, a war..." which wouldn't imply that God fights with a concealed hand against Amalek but rather that God swears by his concealed nature to wage war against Amalek. Note that in its current form, LXX has a Christian provenance, and was routinely redacted by early Christians to fit polemical arguments such as those that were subsequently promulgated by Justin (Dialogue, 49) on this verse.

Dear OneGodOneLord. This is a JEWISH site. Not for Christians. Please leave. We don't care what Christian translations say.

@Shalom, didn't Alexandrian Jews create the LXX for Ptolemy?

@OneGodOneLord The original LXX isn't the same as the expanded 1st/2nd century CE LXX which was either polemically redacted by Christians or is entirely of Christian origin. By the second century CE, the Christian translation became known exclusively as LXX (to contrast with contemporaneous Greek translations of the Hebrew Bible like Symmachus and Theodotion). (I recall reading that Greek translations of the Bible around the turn of the millennium were in general called LXX, such that LXX had become kind of a synecdoche or proprietary eponym to refer to all Hebrew-to-Greek Bible translations).

It's also worth noting the irony (or the intentional villainy) that Justin, one of the earliest Christians to employ the LXX in his polemical arguments, pointed to differences between the Christian LXX and the Hebrew Bible to argue that the LXX must reflect the original text and that the Jews must have altered the Hebrew text to obstinately hide the "truth of Christianity". Aside from the fact that Justin's accusation is implausible and absurd on various grounds, it has been refuted by the discovery of pre-Christian DSS that typically correlate with the masoretic text over the LXX.

@Fred, but not always. Sometimes the DSS sides with the LXX over the MT.

@OneGodOneLord The available DSS on this verse are the Herodian era 4Q14 and the Hasmonean era 4Q22, which both agree with the masoretic text (MT) in Exodus 17:16. Generally, DSS must be approached with nuance because it includes scrolls from a range of dates and sources, some as late as the early Christian era. Some of the scrolls interpretively interpolate a textus receptus, some of them have spelling or transcription errors, and there can be disagreement between DSS texts. It's also possible that the LXX on the Pentateuch used the original LXX as a vorlage and polemically redacted it.
